# Azure Webjob run on a schedule option missing

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-webjobs

I am trying to publish Azure webjob from Visual studio 2015 console application, in azure webjob run mode "run on a schedule" option is missing, I have also installed VS 2017 but still option is missing.

Do I need to install something else? I also installed a Nuget package "Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish" but no success.

Comment: *Technically Scheduled mode does not exist.* It is just an On-Demand WebJob with either a Scheduler job that executes it, or a settings.job file with a CRON expression that uses the built-in scheduler. Which way of scheduling do you want to use? Azure Scheduler or the CRON-expression based one? I believe VS tooling created a Scheduler job to execute the WebJob when that option was selected..

Comment: @juunas, yes, but note that the Azure Scheduler way is no longer recommended, and has been the source of many issues. CRON is the way to go. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The way to do this is to include a `settings.job` file with a CRON schedule. e.g.

```
{
    "schedule": "0 */15 * * * *"
}
```

And make sure to mark your `settings.job` file properties as 'Copy if newer'.

See the *Create a scheduled WebJob using a CRON expression* section in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs for details.

Comment: That does require at least Basic or Standard tier right? :) Azure Scheduler is nice since the job can run even on Free tier plan.

Comment: @juunas yes, that is a fair point, and is noted in the docs. It's still possible to use Scheduler, but the Portal or VS won't help set it up, so you need to manually point it to the WebJob.

Comment: Could you explain why the Scheduler way is not recommended? We have been using it very successfully until now, albeit with pretty long intervals.

Comment: Nothing wrong with scheduler itself. What was always weak/buggy is the VS/Portal integration that tried to make it automatic. But if you go to the scheduler UI and point it to the WebJobs URL, it can definitely be made to work well.

Comment: Ahha, gotcha. That explains why VS doesn't offer it anymore, though it still doesn't quite explain why that way is no longer recommended.

Comment: @DavidEbbo, thanks for the info. While you're answering questions, can you give any guidance as to whether settings.job or a TimerTriggerAttribute is preferred? Or is it personal preference?

Comment: @juunas Maybe 'not recommended' was the wrong phrasing. It's just more advanced, as it requires setting up multiple things, instead of the all-in-one CRON feature where you simply deploy the file with your WebJobs.

Comment: @RobReagan `TimerTriggerAttribute` only makes sense if you need to use the WebJobs **SDK**. For regular WebJobs, which can be as simple as a batch file, `settings.job` is the way to go.

Comment: TimerTriggerAttribute allows you to have different schedules per function, settings.job is for the whole WebJob.

Comment: @juunas yes, these are different scenarios. When you have a regular triggered WebJob, you don't have multiple 'functions' in the first place. It's just one exe / batch / whatever that runs, completes and exists each time.